# How to deallocate the dynamically allocated classes?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

**I have this simple program below:**

```
#include <iostream>            
using namespace std;

class pithikos {

public:
    //constructor
    pithikos(int x, int y){
        xPosition = x;
        yPosition = y;
    }

    //multiplicator of x and y positions
    int xmuly(){
        return xPosition*yPosition;
    }   

private:
    int xPosition;
    int yPosition;
};

int main(void){


//alloccate memory for several number of pithikous
pithikos **pithik = new pithikos*[10];
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
     pithik[i] = new pithikos(i,7);
}

cout << pithik[3]->xmuly() << endl; /*simple print statement for one of the pithiks*/

//create pithikos1 
pithikos pithikos1(5,7);
cout << pithikos1.xmuly() << endl;

//delete alloccated memory
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) delete pithik[i];
delete [] pithik;
cout << pithik[4]->xmuly() << endl;
}
```

The class just takes two numbers and multiplies them and return the value.
But I want the oblects to born and die.

So I allocated in this example 10 objects (pithikos) and then I am testing weather it works.

when I ran the program I get this:

> 21
>
> 35
>
> 28

my problem is: why do I get the value 28 after I used the command?

`delete [] pithik;`

how can I delete the objects if not like this?

Comment: Accessing memory after you free it is undefined behavior.

Comment: `delete` does delete the object, and you are not allowed to dereference the pointer after that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930459/c-delete-it-deletes-my-objects-but-i-can-still-access-the-data

Comment: btw your program is not simple at all. Using `std::vector` is simple, using a `pithikos **` is complicated, error prone and dangerous

Comment: Here is a different link that describes a similar undefined behavior situation (where you are able to access memory that you believe you should not have access): https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/487892

Comment: It's always humorous to me when I see a new C++ programmer expects the memory to just disappear into thin air when using `delete`.

Comment: Don't think the linked question answers this specific question.

Comment: @MartinYork the question doesnt answer the question, but the answer does :P. Dont like the accepted answer too much either, but I think the second one explains a bit. If not there must be a better dupe

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie maybe `free` would have been a better name for what `delete` does, unfortunately that was already taken ;)

Comment: I agree. The accepted answer on the duplicate is not the best answer. There are several other ones in that that are much better.

Comment: In the other two links I cannot see the explicitly how is the "delete" command used in the main program. Here I fully understood how stuff works! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always delete what you create with the `new` keyword. If you create an array of pointers using `new` keyword, use `delete[]` to delete all the pointer elements of the array.

> how can I delete the objects if not like this?

This is the correct way of deleting the objects created with `new` keyword.

> why do I get the value 28 after I used the command?

You should not deference a pointer after it is deleted. it results in an undefined behavior. You may get the old value or a nasty segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

1-Calling delete will mark the memory area as free. It won't necessary reset its old value.

2-Accessing freed memory will surely cause you an undefined behavior so that's extremely inadvisable thing to try