# What happens to a raw pointer if it's shared_ptr is deleted?

Tags: c++

What happens if a C/C++ API returns a raw pointer from an internally used shared_ptr, then the shared_ptr gets "deleted"? Is the raw pointer still valid? How can the API developer clean up the raw pointer when it's not in their control anymore?

As an example:

```
MyClass* thisReturnsAPtr()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> aSharedPtr = std::make_shared<MyClass>(MyClass);
    return aSharedPtr.get();
}
```

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: The raw pointer is now a dangling pointer. That is why we use shared_ptr anyway, to avoid that.

Comment: @user463035818 If I want to expose a C API, but use C++ internally.

Answer (score 3):

If there are no other `shared_ptr` around anymore that still hold a reference to the object and, thus, keep the object alive, then the object will be destroyed, the memory freed, and any still existing pointer that pointed to that object will become a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

In your example above, the pointer returned by the function `thisReturnsAPtr` is guaranteed to be an invalid pointer…

Comment: there cannot be other shared pointers around, in OPs example the pointer returned is guaranteed to be dangling :/

Comment: @user463035818 yes, in that particular example it is. I assumed that the example may not be representative of the actual code, which is why I wanted to make clear that it doesn't depend just on the one `shared_ptr` that may be created inside a function but, in general, depends on whether there is still any `shared_ptr` anywhere that holds ownership. However, I probably should make it more clear that, in the particular example above, the pointer will indeed be definitely invalid…

Answer (score 1):

"What happens to a raw pointer if it's shared_ptr is deleted?" - Nothing. It just becomes invalid to subsequently *use* that pointer.

"a C/C++ API returns a raw pointer from an internally used shared_ptr, then the shared_ptr gets "deleted"? Is the raw pointer still valid?"

No. It is not valid to then use the raw pointer. And the raw pointer does *not* change (to `nullptr`) to indicate that the pointed-to object has been deleted.

It is *your* responsibility to ensure, that if something like that happens, you do not use the raw pointer after it has been invalidated. How you do that is up to you - the language doesn't care/help you.

Using the raw pointer after the object it points to has been deleted, is Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It can *sometimes* be useful to think of smart pointers as a *delayed delete* mechanism. What I mean by that is that if you allocate a class and give it to a smart pointer you are basically asking the smart pointer class to delete that pointer sometime in the future. For a `shared_ptr` that time in the future is when no more `shared_ptr`s exist for it.

Applying this to your code, you create a shared_ptr. You then return the raw pointer. Then your function ends and the only `shared_ptr` to that pointer gets destroyed and so the underlying class is deleted.

This makes your question "If I new a class and delete it then return the original pointer what happens". Which is a lot easier to answer and the answer to that is "badness". There are many answers to this question on stack overflow - such as [C++ delete - It deletes my objects but I can still access the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930459/c-delete-it-deletes-my-objects-but-i-can-still-access-the-data)

Comment: "the answer to that is "badness"" - No, the answer is; Undefined Behaviour.